# Floating element with scrolling using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want div to be move with scroll. It should parallel with scroll. I have made a function it is floating the div but it is not parallel with scroll. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QGak4/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var offset=$('div').offset().top
    var top= $(window).scrollTop();
    var height= offset- top;
    console.log(offset + 'offset')
    console.log(top + 'top')
    console.log(height);

    if(top>57){
    $('div').animate({top:top},100)
    }

   //console.log($('div').offset().top)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/QGak4/1/)**

```
var offset = $("div").offset();
        var topPadding = 75;
      $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("div").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("div").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: It is not parallel with scroll

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem is "position:fixed". Now I am using "position:absolute" and it is working fine. position fixed take coordinates from browser top and position absolute take coordinates from document top

**code**

```
    var offset;
$(function(){
 offset=$('div').offset().top
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top= $(window).scrollTop()+50;
console.log(top + 'top')    
    $('div').animate({top:top},50)    
})
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QGak4/4/)**